# Should I use StringRequest or JsonObjectRequest

Tags: android, android-volley

I am a little confused as to which I am supposed to use.

The API is an trying to hit accepts **regular text post parameters** although its response is a **JSON String**.

Which should I use ?

Answer (score 2):

You Can use `JSON Object Request` for this.

Comment: So I can send regular post parameters ? Or will it send the parameters as a json string ?

Comment: It will depends on API. If your API accept parameters as `JSON` then you can send as `JSON` String. or If you have many parameter let say more then 6 or 7 then `JSON` is preferable.

Comment: No I meant, I know that my API accepts parameters as plain text form fields. Its not in JSON. Will this still work ?

Answer (score 2):

`JsonObjectRequest` and `StringRequest` is different in their parent class and their response. You could find it out if you dig into [volley's source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/idea133/src/com/android/volley/toolbox).

`JsonObjectRequest extends JsonRequest<JSONObject>`

`StringRequest extends Request<String>`

So, if **the response is a JSON String**, then you could just use `JsonObjectRequest` for convenience, since Volley has wrapped the response to be a `JSONObject`.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that made sense. I could do that. Although, I went ahead with https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client it worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

StringRequest - when you want to send api parameter (getParams()) and fetch json response, you can use StringRequest.

JsonObjectRequest - When you only want to fetch the json response and not pass an api parameter, you can use JsonObjectRequest.
JsonObjectRequest can override the same set of methods (getHeaders(), getBodyContentType(), getBody(), getMethod()) like the StringRequest except getParams().